# Does WiX installer depend on the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action, wix3.7

I have a WiX installer containing C# based custom actions.

Does this installer need any .NET Framework installed on host machine in order to execute these C# custom action embed in installer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Unlike Java, .NET needs to be *installed* prior to use, rather than simply *copied* and used. You need to install the version of the .NET framework the C# library was built for or one it is compatible with—e.g., Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or 4.0 Microsoft .NET Framework Full Profile.

Since version 3.6, WiX, in addition to providing tools to author and build Windows Installer packages (and other related files), now provides a bootstrapper/downloader/chainer/bundler with reboot handling capability and package manager for coordinated uninstalls, called Burn.

You can use such a bootstrapper to install both the .NET 4.0 framework and then your installer. See this [article](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn) in addition to the [documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm). In Visual Studio, the "WiX Bootstrapper" template creates a Burn project.

Comment: Is there any way that I can embed these binaries so that Installer works on machines which are not having .Net framework?

Comment: Yes. That's what the bootstrapper does. As a bundler, it can make a single `.exe` file with the .NET Framework installer as well as your `.msi` embedded. Or, you have it bundle only your `.msi` and the installer will download the .NET Framework only on systems don't have it installed already.