# Is the WiX Toolset not designed for deploying C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wix, windows-installer

I have been referencing [the following tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Yf-eDsRrnM) for creating a Setup Project for WiX v3, however, most WiX tutorials on the internet are targeting a C# application as its base project. I am currently building a Visual C++17 Win32 application that I want to deploy (i.e. create a setup `*.msi` installer) using WiX, given how powerful WiX is.

Unfortunately, adding a reference to my C++ project yields a yellow bang exclamation point:
[image]

Moreover, when trying to reference an icon file, for example, in the `Product.wxs` file using `$(var.TimeTrack.ProjectDir)\TimeTrack.ico` reports that it is an "*undefined predecessor variable*." I have tried unloading the WiX Setup Project and tried validating that the yellow banged Visual C++ project reference is referring to the correct path in the `*.wixproj` file. The include path appears to be correct:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TimeTrack\TimeTrack.vcxproj">
    <Name>TimeTrack</Name>

    <!-- More not shown. -->
</ItemGroup>
```

I did a bit of digging and I cam across [this StackOverflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905373/does-wix-installer-depend-on-the-net-framework) that indicated that WiX is dependent on .NET framework. In addition, there seems to be a lot of very old postings (e.g. [example 1](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Votive-unable-to-reference-C-projects-td709339.html)) on this topic and I just am not entirely sure if I am just misunderstanding something here. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671950/is-it-possible-to-integrate-c-code-inside-wix-project), the WiX project cannot refer to any C/C++ code, but this appears to be referring to "*Custom Actions*," which appear to be an entirely different topic (?).

All in all, **am I doing something wrong or is WiX not capable of deploying C++ applications?** Is WiX only meant for deploying C# applications?

Comment: WiX creates Windows Installer Databases.  Windows Installer came out in 1999 prior to .NET Framework existing.

Answer (score 0):

WiX has a development dependency on .NET but not an install time dependency.

Files are files.  WiX doesn't care if they are C, C++, VB, PowerBuilder, Delphi, .NET, NodeJS, Electron or whatever.

The main differences for .NET vs C/C++ is:

1) .NET typically requires you to check that .NET is installed or author a bootstrapper to install it.

2) .NET core can typically be packaged with the app privately without a system wide installation of .NET core.

3) C/C++ typically requires installing the VCRedist via a bootstrapper or statically linking the files into your application.

4) .NET is "AnyCPU" where as C/C++ is compiled for the platform.  MSI is compiled for the platoform. This means for .NET a single x86 MSI can deploy a .NET app that might run 32bit or 64bit depending on how it was built.  For C/C++ you might need to create a 32bit MSI and a 64bit MSI for your app.

I have a FOSS tool that helps with learning and authoring WiX.  You can read about it here:

http://www.github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials

The tutorials only hav C# examples but pull requests are welcome.  Create your C/C++ application  and use a postbuild copy command to stage the files to the Installer\Deploy folder and everything else is mostly the same.

Comment: I appreciate the insight here. I think my only question I have is, **how do you add a C++ project reference without a yellow exclamation mark?** If you create a new Win32 app (`File->New->Project->Installed->Visual C++->Widows Desktop->Windows Desktop Application`) and then try and add this as a reference to your WiX proejct, a yellow exclamation mark **always** shows up. What's going on?

Comment: There is nothing that says you have to use project references in WiX projects.  Specifically I prefer not to.  Take a look at my tutorials to see another way.

Comment: I just copy files to an output location with other means and use [preprocessor constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501700/129130) to allow source path override ([WiX preprocessor documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html)). [Here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766353/129130) - [direct source file link](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/CompilerVariables.wxs).